# ImageView with only two corners rounded?

Tags: android

I want to have an ImageView with top right corner & bottom left corner rounded.

> ```
> <corners 
> android:topRightRadius="10dp"
> android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
> android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
> android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
> ```

Tried the above code , but it's not working.Please help!

Comment: how are you using all together?

Comment: set some solid color with corners, and set whole as background to imageview

Comment: pls suggest how to make only  top right & bottom left corner of image view rounded? rohit @  i have done that but shape appearing is of rectangle not with two corners rounded

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088596/how-to-make-an-image-corner-programatically may be useful

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) is the best library I could find.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<corners android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

This is my drawable shape.xml in drawable folder. And I am using this drawable to set imageviews background.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

Done It will appear when you run app on device/emulator (Wont appear in xml graphical layout)

Comment: thanx i was looking into xml,working fine on device

Comment: I am not getting this to work, was there anything else I needed to do in addition to this?

Comment: I don't think this works. You're creating a background with rounded corners, but the ImageView is left untouched.

Comment: Ofcourse, this wont change actual view, but I just solved whatever op is doing wrong..

Comment: It makes a rounded corner for an `ImageView` but not for the Image inside it.

Comment: it will not clip image content in rounded shape

Answer (score 2):

> I am using this it works fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />

    </shape>
```